# Angular - How to Display Foreign Key Value instead of ID

Tags: angular, laravel, postman

I created two(2) tables

**Laravel:**

**short_code**

```
class Shortcode extends Model
{
protected $table = 'short_code';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'descriptions',
    'telco_id',
    'created_at', 

public function telco() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Telco');
}     
}
```

**telco**

```
class Telco extends Model
{
protected $table = 'telco';

protected $fillable = [
  'name' ,
  'deascription',
  'country',
  'created_at',
];      

public function shortcode()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\ShortCode');
}     
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function indexShortcode()
{
    if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
        $shortcodes = Shortcode::all();
    else 
        $shortcodes = Shortcode::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();       
}
```

API Route

```
Route::get('indexShortcode', 'ApiController@indexShortcode');
```

I am using Angular 7 to get endpoints from Laravel 5.8 API. I want to display name (value and not key) from telco table. short_code is the main table.

I have created the model.ts, service.ts component.ts and component.html

**Angular**

**model:  shortcode**

```
 import { User } from '../models/user';
 import { Telco } from '../models/telco';

 export class Shortcode {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 description: string;
 telco_id: number;
 telco?: Telco;   

constructor() {}
}
```

**shortcode.service.ts**

```
import { Shortcode } from '../models/shortcode';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';
import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from '../shared/_services/http- handle-error.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShortcodeService {

private readonly apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
private shortcodeUrl = this.apiUrl;
private handleError: HandleError;  

constructor(
private http: HttpClient,
httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler ) {
  this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('ShortcodeService');
}

/** GET shortcodes from shortcodes endpoint */
getShortcodes (): Observable<Shortcode[]> {
 return this.http.get<Shortcode[]>(this.shortcodeUrl + '/indexShortcode')
.pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError('getShortcodes', []))
);
} 
}
```

**shortcode.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';

import {ExcelService} from '../../../services/excel.service';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ShortcodeService } from '../../../services/shortcode.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Shortcode } from '../../../models/shortcode';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sms-shortcode-my',
templateUrl: './sms-shortcode-my.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sms-shortcode-my.component.scss']
})
export class SmsShortcodeMyComponent implements OnInit {

shortcodes: Shortcode[];
isLoading: Boolean = false;
public searchText: string; 
public filter: string; 
shortcodePosts: Shortcode[] = [];

constructor(
    private shortcodeService: ShortcodeService,
    private excelService:ExcelService, 
    private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,) { }

ngOnInit() {

 // Get shortcode detail
 this.getShortcodes();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
document.body.className = '';
}


 getShortcodes(): void {
// this.isLoading = true;
this.spinnerService.show();
this.shortcodeService.getShortcodes()
  .subscribe(
    response => this.handleResponse(response),
    error => this.handleError(error),
    ()=>this.spinnerService.hide()
    );
 }

protected handleResponse(response: Shortcode[]) {
  this.isLoading = false,
  this.shortcodes = response;
 }
 protected handleError(error: any) {
this.isLoading = false,
console.error(error);
 }  
 }
```

**shortcode.component,html**

```
                      <tr  *ngFor="let shortcode of shortcodes; let i = index">
                    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                  <td>{{shortcode?.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{shortcode?.description}}</td>
                  <td>{{shortcode?.telco?.name}}</td>                               
              </tr>
```

I used

> {{shortcode?.telco?.name}}

to display the telco name (foreign key value) instead of the

> {{shortcode?.telco_id}}

but nothing is being displayed. I checked console, nothing is there.

Please where have I got it wrong and what do I do?

Comment: Missing you controller code on php side. But all you have to do is eager load your relationship: `ModelName::with ('relationship_name')->get()`

Comment: Please add controller code

Comment: I have added the controller

Comment: @Sagar Gautam   I have added the controller

Comment: @Elias Soares    I have added the controller. How do I do eager load of my relationship

Comment: @user11352561 I have added my answer have a look ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to eager load relationship,

```
public function indexShortcode()
{
     if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
        $shortcodes = Shortcode::with('telco')->get();
    else 
        $shortcodes = Shortcode::with('telco')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();       
}
```

Now, you can access name like:

```
shortcode.telco.name
```

Comment: when I implemented it I got this error:     Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: @user11352561 It's my problem there should be get instead of all.